# Ouput date in ISO8601 date-time format

Tags: marketing-cloud, date, ssjs

I need to output a date in ISO8601 date-time format in Salesforce using SSJS.

Salesforce is storing in format 'Thursday, 1 August 2019 5:00 PM'.

I have tried Write(current.date.toISOString()) but doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it in AMPscript using Format Date function: https://ampscript.guide/formatdate/

Example: 
`set @dateISO = FormatDate(@dateString,"iso")`

You can pass the date variable form SSJS to AMPscript using SetValue function: https://ampscript.guide/setvalue/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
 Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");

 var ssjsVersion = Format(new Date(),'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz');
 var ampVersion = Platform.Function.TreatAsContent("\%\%=FormatDate(Now(),'iso')=\%\%");

</script>

<p>ssjsVersion = <ctrl:var name=ssjsVersion/></p>
<p>ampVersion = <ctrl:var name=ampVersion/></p>
```